# Google Docs Forms: Create Checklist Item with adjacent Textfield

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Using Google Docs Forms, I'd like to create a checklist with a "quantity" and "comments" textfield adjacent to each checklist item. Is it possible to do this without writing a custom script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to change the the default form layout directly from the Google Forms editor.

## Alternatives

- Use a HTML editor to change the resulting form. The resulting html file could be hosted in Google Drive or in another web server.
- Use [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) of Google Apps Script to create a web app and submit the answers to a Google spreadsheet. Further details are out of the scope of this site, maybe you could get help on this at http://stackoverflow.com.
  `

  ## References
- [Add and edit questions, headers, images, videos, and page breaks - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en)
- [Host webpages with Drive - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)